# Oracle to SQL Server : dynamic query with limited rowset returned

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, row-number, rownum

I have a difficult (if not impossible) problem to ask a solution for. I have an Oracle query, and I have to translate it to T-SQL syntax.

The query looks like this in Oracle:

```
__select_wrapper=select * from(
     select rownum row_num, inner__c3p__query.* 
     from ({0}) inner__c3p__query) 
     where row_num>@offset and (row_num<=(@offset+@count) or (@count<1))
```

This comes from a properties file. Basically, this one line executes any SQL query, names the resultset "inner__c3p__query", and selects everything from it and also a rownum. Then, it filters the result by the rownum: >@offset and <=@offset + @count. So, practically, it executes any SQL query, and returns a limited rowset, e.g. from the 10th row to the 20th.

Now, my job is to transform this into T-SQL. I spent one and a half day looking up every possible idea, but so far, I haven't succeeded. I tried a great many things, neither of them worked. The problem is, I can't use `ROW_NUMBER()` function, because it requires at least one column in the `OVER()` clause, and I can't provide any, because the actual query is only determined at runtime.

Do you guys have any idea, or is it really impossible to do on the DB side?

Thanks in advance!

Gabe

Comment: You should be aware that this kind of query is *extremely* vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @RBarryYoung yes, I understand, but thank you for the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I have a lot of reservations about this kind of approach, especially wrt SQL Injection attacks, the following should work:

```
select * from(
 select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (Select NULL)) row_num, 
    inner__c3p__query.* 
 from ({0}) inner__c3p__query) 
 where row_num>@offset and (row_num<=(@offset+@count) or (@count<1))
```

Unfortunately, since the ordering column never changes, if you are trying to use this for paging, you cannot guarantee that the same row_num is always assigned to the same row in repeated executions.

Comment: Does Oracle guarantee that `rownum` will always be the same?

Comment: @Hogan not sure, it think that it may if the subquery itself is uniquely ordered.  I know for a fact that SQL Server does not insure ordering for interior `ORDER BY`s unless there's a TOP clause involved.

Answer (score 1):

ROW_NUMBER() only requires a column in the ORDER BY part (otherwise how do you order them?)

If the original was a random order then just pick a random column in the query (like the first one.)  In an ORDER BY you can use column numbers... just use the first column or the number one.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1)
```

Comment: How come I didn't think of this? It's so simple, it frustrates me a lot for not figuring out this one. Thank you, good man!

Comment: Same caveat as I stated in my answer: if the column that you pick does not have unique values in the returned rowset, then you cannot be certain that the same row numbers will be assigned on repeated executions, a problem for paging uses.

Comment: @RBarryYoung yes, that's true, and besides, it's not even working. I just tested it, and the result is: Windowed functions and NEXT VALUE FOR functions do not support integer indices as ORDER BY clause expressions.

Comment: Oh, that's right, there are some obscure restrictions on the column expressions allowed for `OVER( ORDER BY ..)`, that's why I always use the SELECT NULL trick.